# Firebase Cloud Function value returns "null" in Dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

inline editor in Dialogflow cloud function returns null for value which exists.

Cloud function from inline editor deployed without any errors.
Weebhook response "Webhook execution successful"

Have tried reading other values in the same item, all returning null.

Function with aim to read temp

```
function handleReadTemp(agent) {
    return admin.database().ref('device/data/subdata/').limitToLast(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    const value = snapshot.child('Temp').val();
     agent.add(`The temperature right now is ${value}`); 
    });
  }
```

df
Structure of Firebase realtime database is as follows;[link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMeWa.jpg

```
root
  |
  device
       |
        data
          |
          subdata
              |
              - record1
                    |- Temp:"33.35"
              -  record2
                    |- Temp: "34"
```

Goal is to read the the 34 from Temp of record2 - so the Temp of the last record.

My aim was that 
`admin.database().ref('device/data/subdata/').limitToLast(1).once('value').then((snapshot) =>`

gets the last record (record2 Note: record names are randomly generated so I cannot know what the next record will be called)

and then `const value = snapshot.child('Temp').val();`

Would get the value of Temp which is a child of record2.

Cloudfunction logs throw no errors [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgzHf.jpg

Agent response in Dialogflow: `temperature is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal because the content of the `snapshot` [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) corresponds to the following object:

```
{"record2":{"Temp":34}}
```

You can verify it by doing `console.log(snapshot.val());`

So, you should do something like:

```
.....
const value = snapshot
            .child(Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0] + '/Temp')
            .val();
agent.add(`The temperature right now is ${value}`);  
.....
```

Comment: thank you for the console tip makes sense and solution works :)